# Moving in a friends villager with max villagers

Tags: animal-crossing-new-horizons

My island currently has ten villagers on it. I want Jacques to move out. My friend has Tad in boxes today.  Can I convince Tad to move in and kick Jacques out?

Answer (score 2):

No, in order to invite a villager in boxes you need an open plot on your own island.